# Error en endpoint con flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Estoy realizando un `EndPoint` con `flask`,en `python` el cual debe recibir dos datos un precio y un id, y madar uan respuesta en tipo `Json` la repuesta que espero es como esta: `{"success":"ok","total":monto*id/4}` pero solo recivo un `404` de respuesta ¿Alguna solución?

Codigo:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', threaded=True)
@app.route('/procesingEndpoint', methods=['GET'])
def respond():
    transactionamount = request.args.get("transactionamount")
    print(request.query_string.json)
    return datatransaction(request.json)
def datatransaction(data):
transactionamount = data[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

`respond` ó `datatransaction` deben regresar un `dict`. Si la función no tiene un `return` te regresa un `None`.

```
def datatransaction(data):
    monto = ...
    id = ...
    return {"success":"ok","total":monto*id/4}
```

Answer (score 0):

primero se deben definir las rutas y luego correr la app...

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/procesingEndpoint', methods=['GET'])
def respond():
    transactionamount = request.args.get("transactionamount")
    print(request.query_string.json)
    return datatransaction(request.json)
def datatransaction(data):
    transactionamount = data[12]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', threaded=True)
```